# how extract id and send it in axios

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vuetify.js

i have vuetify

```html
 <v-col cols="12" md="8">
<v-select :items="driverName" v-bind:id="editedItem.driverId" v-model="editedItem.score" label="score"></v-select>
</v-col>
```

and me need know resulr id `v-bind:id="editedItem.driverId"` in `:items`  keep

```html
  <v-data-table
    :headers="headers"
    :items="desserts"
    sort-by="calories"
    class="elevation-1"
  >
```

i get data with api in axios 
here my code https://github.com/ivan556258/crm/blob/master/src/views/table/AppBillAll.vue

Comment: Does v-select emit a change event? If it does, you can use `v-bind.sync="editedItem.driverId"`

Comment: @Mruf thanks you but no

Comment: please explain further

Answer (score 0):

```html
<v-col cols="12" md="8">
     
     <v-select :items="drivers" item-value="_id"  item-text="lastname"  v-model="editedItem.score" label="Счёт">
     </v-select>
</v-col>
```

`console.log(this.editedItem.score);` // here id